# Assigning value to datarow from Collection

Tags: c#

I have a WCF service which returns a collection upon calling method given below. But the problem is when assigning these values to datarow, it is not displaying data instead its showing "ServiceReference1.CustomerDetails" (referring to the collection itself)

```
 ServiceReference1.transactionProcessingSystemClient obj = new transactionProcessingSystemClient();

        Label1.Text = "Account Statement for " + Session["account"].ToString();
        IList<CustomerDetails> objAccountDetails = new List<CustomerDetails>();
        String id = Session["account"].ToString();
        objAccountDetails = obj.GetCustomerTransactionDetails(id);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("No.", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Amount", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Transaction Type", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Date", typeof(string)));
        for (int index = 0; index < objAccountDetails.Count; index++)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            int iRowNo = index + 1;
            dr["No."] = iRowNo;
            dr["Amount"] = objAccountDetails[index];
            dr["Transaction Type"] = objAccountDetails[index];
            dr["Date"] = objAccountDetails[index];
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);                                            
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

For your information, I am doing this manually as I want to display only certain data from the collection. When I assign the "objAccountDetails" to gridView it works fine.

Any comment or ideas please...

Comment: You aren't assigning any values to the row fields, you are assigning the same object collection object to all string fields. The only valid string representation of an arbitrary object is the object's type name. If you want eg to pass the customer's amount, use `objAccountDetails[index].Amount`. Better yet, assign the customer to a temporary variable insted. of accessing it using an index each time

Comment: BTW, you *don't* need to convert the list to a DataTable. All data-bound objects can bind to collections. Just set the data binding information of each grid column to refer to the appropriate customer property.

Comment: Many thanks, so far after making those changes its working.

Comment: How do I set row data for each column as I mentioned in my question - say my collection is returning someones dob, name, address, phone but in grid I want to show only name and address (for example)

Comment: dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {objAccountDetails});  The order of the array must match the order of the columns you are filling.

Comment: many thanks I will give it a try